# Does tensorflow Estimator take different batches for workers when MirroredStrategy is used?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am using GANEstimator with MirroredStrategy to work on multiple GPUs of single instance. `input_fn` in my case is `tf.data.Dataset` with the following settings:

```
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
dataset = dataset.batch(self.batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(100)
```

The reason why I am asking this is that do I need to specify something like `dataset.shard()` manually to have different data being passed to workers? I am digging in the code of [Estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py), and [MirroredStrategy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py), but it is unclear to me what is going on. Additional confuse is created from the [description of distributed strategies](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute):

```
MirroredStrategy: This does in-graph replication with synchronous 
training on many GPUs on one machine. Essentially, we create copies of all
variables in the model's layers on each device. We then use all-reduce 
to combine gradients across the devices before applying them 
to the variables to keep them in sync.

CollectiveAllReduceStrategy: This is a version of MirroredStrategy 
for multi-worker training.
```

So does MirroredStratedy use only one worker? I don't understand it. I need to specify batch size equal to capacity of one tower, otherwise I get OOM. Can someone please point me to the code and explain how does such a simple setup work with batches:

```
def create_dataset():
    ...
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
    dataset = dataset.batch(self.batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(100)
    return dataset



NUM_GPUS = 4
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(num_gpus=NUM_GPUS)

optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01, use_locking=True)
optimizer_d = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01, use_locking=True)

config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=100, 
          save_summary_steps=1, keep_checkpoint_max=50, 
          train_distribute=strategy)

# I have more hooks here, just simplified to show 
def get_hooks_fn(GANTrainOps):

    disjoint_train_hook_func = tfgan.get_sequential_train_hooks(
                 train_steps=tfgan.GANTrainSteps(10, 1)
                 ) # g steps, d steps
    disjoint_train_hooks = disjoint_train_hook_func(GANTrainOps)
    return [update_hook, summary_hook] + disjoint_train_hooks


# Create GAN estimator.
gan_estimator = tfgan.estimator.GANEstimator(
    model_dir = '/data/checkpoints/estimator_model', 
    generator_fn = generator_fn,
    discriminator_fn = discriminator_fn,
    generator_loss_fn = generator_loss_fn, 
    discriminator_loss_fn = discriminator_loss_fn, 
    generator_optimizer = optimizer,
    discriminator_optimizer = optimizer_d, 
    use_loss_summaries=True,
    config=config,
    get_hooks_fn=get_hooks_fn)


gan_estimator.train(input_fn=create_dataset, steps=10000)
```

Thanks!

The code of MirroredStrategy contains:

1) Weird wording:

> The multi-worker version of this class maps one replica to one device on a
>     worker. It mirrors all model variables on all replicas. For example, if you
>     have two `worker`s and each `worker` has 4 GPUs, it will create 8 copies of
>     the model variables on these 8 GPUs. Then like in MirroredStrategy(???), each
>     replica performs their computation with their own copy of variables unless in
>     cross-replica model where variable or tensor reduction happens.

2)

> auto_shard_dataset: whether to auto-shard the dataset when there are
>       multiple workers.

This parameter is False by default.

EDIT:

So far I found that [`tf.estimator.train()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py) after some time points to what seems to be `strategy.make_input_fn_iterator()`:

```
def _get_iterator_from_input_fn(self, input_fn, mode, distribution=None):
    if distribution is not None:
      iterator = distribution.make_input_fn_iterator(
          lambda _: self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
      input_hooks = [
          estimator_util.DistributedIteratorInitializerHook(iterator)]
    else:
      result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
      iterator = result.make_initializable_iterator()
      input_hooks = [estimator_util._DatasetInitializerHook(iterator)]  
return iterator, input_hooks
```

`make_input_fn_iterator()`

But it was removed from the code of [MirroredStrategy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py) and is no longer there! I don't understand how it works and where the dataset is actually split.

EDIT2: I can't find line `make_input_fn_iterator` in my tensorflow 1.12.0 distribution with grep. Seems like it's totally absent in the code.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after spending some time investigating github, I found that it is already different from my tf 1.12.0. So, going down in the local files of 1.12.0 gave me:

GANEstimator inherits tf.python.estimator.Estimator

```
Estimator.init():

# The distribute field contains an instance of DistributionStrategy.
    self._train_distribution = self._config.train_distribute
```

Then the path down is:

```
tf.contrib.gan.GANEstimator -> tf.python.estimator.Estimator.train() --> 
tf.python.estimator.Estimator._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners) --> 
._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners) --> 
._get_iterator_from_input_fn(input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self._train_distribution) --> 
distribution.distribute_dataset(lambda: self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
```

which calls in my case for `MirrorredStrategy.distribute_dataset():`

```
def distribute_dataset(self, dataset_fn):
    if self._cluster_spec:
      return values.MultiWorkerDataset(
          partial(self._call_dataset_fn, dataset_fn), self._worker_device_map,
          self._prefetch_on_device, self._auto_shard_dataset)
    else:
      return values.PerDeviceDataset(
          self._call_dataset_fn(dataset_fn), self._devices,
          self._prefetch_on_device)
```

`tensorflow/python/training/distribute.py`:

```
  def _call_dataset_fn(self, dataset_fn):
    result = dataset_fn()
    if not isinstance(result, dataset_ops.Dataset):
      raise ValueError(
          "dataset_fn() must return a tf.data.Dataset when using a "
          "DistributionStrategy.")
    return result
```

I assume `PerDeviceDataset` is used, so finally I find these two classes in `values.py`:

```
class PerDeviceDataset(object):
  """Like `tf.data.Dataset` split devices, producing `PerDevice` data."""

  def __init__(self, dataset, devices, prefetch_on_device=None):
    self._devices = devices

    # Default to using prefetching in graph mode, unless specified.
    # TODO(priyag): Enable prefetching in eager mode.
    self._prefetch_on_device = prefetch_on_device
    if self._prefetch_on_device is None:
      self._prefetch_on_device = not context.executing_eagerly()
    assert not (self._prefetch_on_device and context.executing_eagerly()), (
        "Prefetching is only supported in graph mode currently")

    if self._prefetch_on_device:
      self._dataset = dataset.apply(
          prefetching_ops_v2.prefetch_to_devices(self._devices))
    else:
      # TODO(priyag): If dropping remainder is not appropriate, find another
      # approach to distributing the dataset when not possible to divide evenly.
      # Possibly not an issue when we start using PartitionedDataset.
      self._dataset = dataset.batch(len(devices), drop_remainder=True)

  def make_one_shot_iterator(self):
    """Get a one time use iterator for the distributed PerDeviceDataset."""
    dataset_iterator = self._dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    return PerDeviceDataIterator(dataset_iterator, self._devices,
                                 self._prefetch_on_device)

  def make_initializable_iterator(self):
    """Get an initializable iterator for the distributed PerDeviceDataset."""
    dataset_iterator = self._dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    return PerDeviceDataIterator(dataset_iterator, self._devices,
                                 self._prefetch_on_device)


class PerDeviceDataIterator(object):
  """An iterator (like `tf.data.Iterator`) into a `PerDeviceDataset`."""

  def __init__(self, iterator, devices, prefetch_on_device=None):
    self._iterator = iterator
    self._devices = devices
    self._prefetch_on_device = prefetch_on_device

  @property
  def initializer(self):
    return self._iterator.initializer

  def get_next(self, name=None):
    """Scatter the input across devices."""
    if self._prefetch_on_device:
      data_list = self._iterator.get_next(name=name)
      index = dict(zip(self._devices, data_list))
    else:
      batch = self._iterator.get_next(name=name)
      index = {}
      def get_ith(i):
        return lambda x: x[i]

      for i, d in enumerate(self._devices):
        index[d] = nest.map_structure(get_ith(i), batch)
        if context.executing_eagerly():
          with ops.device(d):
            index[d] = nest.map_structure(array_ops.identity, index[d])

    return regroup(index)
```

So, as far as I understand, and first, my `dataset_fn()` function is just called to obtain dataset object, and then a batch with size of number of GPUs is applied on top of it. Elements of this batch which must be actual batches defined in my dataset initialization inside `dataset_fn()` are assigned to different devices.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis! I am also confused by MirrorStrategy's batch strategy. So does it mean that the batch_size in user's "dataset_fn()" is the actual batch_size on each GPU? In other words, MirrorStrategy won't divide user specified batch_size in "dataset_fn()" into "batch_size / num_gpu", is that correct?

Comment: @xyd Yes, it seems to create a 'batch over batches', at least if `tf.data.Dataset` was provided as return value of `dataset_fn()`, and take num_gpu actual batches from it, assigning them to different GPUs. Also, if you are training Estimator with some complicated network like GAN, I want to strongly advice you to double check inside your network that all the variables are reused properly and subnets are not just doubled somehow on the graph. I've stuck into this problem with trying to implement WGAN-GP in GANEstimator, which needs extra call to discriminator subnetwork

Comment: I noticed that MirroredStrategy seems to always drop remainder. Is that your experience as well?

Comment: @JohnJiang I'm sorry, it's a very long time since I used Estimator last time... Don't think I can help

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide some clarification in case it helps, but really not sure if that's your point.

> does MirroredStrategy use only one worker?

Yes. MirroredStrategy is intended to work only on one Worker (a.k.a one node, one computer, ...)

> I need to specify batch size equal to the capacity of one tower

No. You need to multiply the batch size to the sum of towers.

*Note: For reference, Tower is a copy of the model, which is equal to the number of GPUs, also called replicas*

From this [Keras tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras), here is how to simply calculate the batch size:

```
BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 64
BATCH_SIZE = BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

train_dataset = mnist_train.map(scale).cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
eval_dataset = mnist_test.map(scale).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

In that case, the batch size per GPU is 64. Then multiplied by the number of GPUs.
Why multiplying by the number of GPUs?
To compute the gradient and the loss. it will be divided by the total amount of batch size (and not the GPU batch size)

> 1. Weird wording:

This is comparing the MirroredStrategy to the Multi-WorkerStrategy. In the case of a cluster, your tower will be replicated to every worker (e.g. 2 nodes in this example). Each worker will be responsible to distribute the model to their GPUs (e.g. 4 GPUs in that case). In that example, you will have 8 copies of your models.

> [...] Then like in MirroredStrategy(???), each replica performs their computation with their own copy of variables [...]

Whatever you use multi-workers or a single worker, each GPU (or replica) will compute their model independently and sync afterward.
I guess they mention that "copy of variables", because there is another distributed computing topology with a Parameter Server (ps) where the ps will gather the weights of all replicas, sum it, and redistribute it to all replicas for the next round.